# SharePoint 2019 OnPremise - Stop Inheriting Permissions Inheritance on subsites

Tags: 2019, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-permissions

The site setup goes like this: MainSite --> SubSite.

Permissions on MainSite

[image]

User (tsp5070_ex_farm) is also added to Style Resource Readers.

[image]

I set Stop Inheriting Permissions and user added "Edit Permission" on SubSite.

[image]

On WebApp -> SubSite when I logged:

- in modern view still asked credential

[image]

- classic view did not ask credential, but if I went e.g. Home Page where it was not possible to switch to classic mode so it still asked credential

[image]

Why does it still ask me to log in once I logged it? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It’s the default behavior since the user has only limited access permission in the main site. They don’t have permission to view modern pages.

As a workaround, you can create a new permission level in the main site, select 'View Application Pages' list permission and 'Open' site permission, then grant this permission level to the user in the main site.

Clear the browser cache and login to check the result.

Comment: I created a new permission level with permissions: View Application Pages, Open. I have added permission level to the user on the main site. Cleared the browser cache and logged. I signed in and about a moment require a login again. I cannot access the main site, I have access to the subsite.